# html download attribute opening new tab instead of downloading file

Tags: html, angular, image, download

I have an Angular 4 website, which allows the users to download an image from an Amazon S3 bucket, to do this I use an anchor with the download attribute, but instead of downloading the image it gets opened in a new tab.
I tested it with Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

This is what I have in the template:

```
<a mat-raised-button color="accent" [href]="downloadPath" download matTooltip="Download file to pc." *ngIf="isFinalReport()">
    <mat-icon>file_download</mat-icon>
    DOWNLOAD
</a>
```

The download path is something like this: https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/environment/imageName.jpg

I have also tested it with several images from around the web and doesnt work with any, but if I use a local image (C:/Users/User/Desktop/images/image.jpg) it works perfectly.

Any idea why this doesnt work and how to fix it?
If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
To directly download the image , you can try with 
<a [href]="javascript:downloadImage(downloadLink);"></a>

downloadImage(downloadLink) {
this.mediaService.getImage(downloadLink).subscribe(
  (res) => {
             const a = document.createElement('a');
             a.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
             a.download = title;
             document.body.appendChild(a);
             a.click();
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Took some research, but I found that using the backend is the best approach to this problem. I was creating an anchor tag that upon clicking should download the s3 url, but instead it would open a new tab with the object. The problem is most likely caused by one or two things. One is that browsers do not allow for cross origin downloads directly. The second revolves around your Reponse Content Disposition. Here is my approach to getting s3 to download directly to the filesystem:

Backend (I use Django and boto3):

```
    def get_file(self, obj):      
        client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                              aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

        return client.generate_presigned_url(
            'get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
                'Key': obj.key,
                'ResponseContentDisposition': 'attachment',
            },
            ExpiresIn=600)
```

Frontend (using Angular):

```
<a [href]="what_i_returned_from_backend" [download]="answer.png" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">Download</a>
```